# WebFlux: how to use the block() method inside onErrorResume?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-webclient

I'm new to reactive programming
I want to save the object to the DB when handling an error, but as far as I know, calling the block() method is not the best practice

```
 mailFailureRepository.save(failure).block();
```

Is there a way to do this without interrupting the flow?
I think I should rebuild the thread chain, but I don't quite understand how to do it in my case

I will also be glad of any information resources

```
  public Mono<Object> sendEmail(SendEmailRequest request)
          throws MailTemplateNotSupportedException, ExactTargetException {
        log.debug("Send email process started.");
        return validateRequestAndSendMail(request)
            .onErrorResume(error -> {
              if (error instanceof ExactTargetException ex) {
                MailFailure failure = MailFailure.builder()
                    .templateKey(request.getTemplateKey())
                    .templateParams(request.getTemplateParams() != null ? request.getTemplateParams().toString() : null)
                    .subscriberHash(request.getSubscriberHash())
                    .email(request.getEmail())
                    .responseStatus(ex.getStatus())
                    .responsePayload(ex.getBody())
                    .build();
                mailFailureRepository.save(failure).block();
                return Mono.error(error);
              }
              return Mono.error(error);
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not save and then return error without blocking:

```java
        public Mono <Object> sendEmail(SendEmailRequest request)
                throws MailTemplateNotSupportedException, ExactTargetException {
            log.debug("Send email process started.");
            return validateRequestAndSendMail(request)
                    .onErrorResume(error -> {
            Mono<Object> errorMono = Mono.error(error);
            if (error instanceof ExactTargetException ex) {
                return mailFailureRepository.save(buildFailureEmail(request))
                        .thenReturn(errorMono);
            }
            return errorMono;
            });
        }
        private MailFailure buildFailureEmail(SendEmailRequest request) {
            return MailFailure.builder()
                .templateKey(request.getTemplateKey())
                .templateParams(request.getTemplateParams() != null ? request.getTemplateParams().toString() : null)
                .subscriberHash(request.getSubscriberHash())
                .email(request.getEmail())
                .responseStatus(ex.getStatus())
                .responsePayload(ex.getBody())
                .build();
        }
```

Comment: this code wont work, you need a return statemant `return mailFailureRepository.save(buildFailureEmail(request))
                        .thenReturn(errorMono);` as `thenReturn` will throw away what is returned from `save` function but it wont return from the function.

Comment: I misses `return statement`. Thanks